# Convert from byte* to byte[]

Tags: c#

How do I convert a pointer to a byte array?

The first byte indicates the number of bytes to follow.

Comment: Is it really C# question or C/C++ question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The safe thing to do is to make a *copy* of the data pointed to.

If you have a byte* then you can of course just write the code yourself:

```
byte* source = whatever;
int size = source[0]; // first byte is size;
byte[] target = new byte[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    target[i] = source[i+1];
```

Easy peasy.

If instead of a byte* you have an IntPtr then you can use this helpful method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx

There are lots of helpful methods on the Marshal class.

Comment: Random observation: I've always found it odd that `Buffer.BlockCopy` doesn't have an overload for `byte*`. Of course, it is also pretty rare I need `unsafe`...

Comment: From your wording, it seems there is an _unsafe_ way to have the final `byte[]` reference point to the _uncopied_ data. I doubt that this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the `byte*` *isn't* the array object. You *can* get the address of the *data* (using `fixed` etc), but an arbitrary `byte*` does *not* have to be the start of the data - it could be at offset 17, for example.

So I would recommend either:

- pass the `byte[]` around instead
- (or) create a *new* `byte[]` and [copy over](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28k1s2k6(VS.80).aspx) the data you want